# Exporting from MS Excel to MS Access with intermediate processing

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an application which produces reports in Excel (.XLS) format. I need to append the data from these reports to an existing table in a MS Access 2010 database. A typical record is:

```
INC000000004154 Closed  Cbeebies    BBC Childrens   HQ6 monitor wall dropping out.  HQ6 P3  3/7/2013 7:03:01 PM 3/7/2013 7:03:01 PM 3/7/2013 7:14:15 PM The root cause of the problem was the power supply to the PC which was feeding the monitor. HQ6 Monitor wall dropping out. BBC Third Party Contractor supply this equipment.
```

The complication is that I need to do some limited processing on the data. Viz

[image: diagram]

Specifically I need to do a couple of lookups converting names to numbers and also parse a date-string (the report for some reason puts the dates in to the spreadsheet in text format rather than date format).

Now I *could* do this in Python using XLRD/XLWT but would much prefer to do it in Excel or Access. Does anyone have any advice on a good way to approach this? I would very much prefer NOT to use VBA so could I do something like record an MS Excel macro and then execute that macro on the newly created XLS file?

Comment: Umm, if you "record an MS Excel macro" you're "using VBA". Please explain why you "would very much prefer NOT to use VBA".

Comment: Because I have tried programming in it in the past and it is utterly dreadful. If a Macro automatically generates working code for me then that's fine but the idea of programming in something that's a combination of FORTRAN II and Druidic Runes does not appeal. Does that explain?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks. I suspected it was merely a case of "language snobbery" but I wanted to make sure since you said that you "would much prefer to do it in Excel or Access". Based on your description of the processing required, VBA could easily handle it. (Really, this ain't "rocket science" we're talking about here.) However, if VBA offends your delicate sensibilities then perhaps you should continue searching for an alternative.

Comment: No. I'm not proud. I've even programmed in FORTH. But VB doesn't justify the learning curve in getting to speed in its inconsistencies and limitations and general gnarliness combined with poor documentation and debugging tools. But thanks for asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly import some Excel data into MS Access, but if your requirement is to do some processing because then I don't see how you will be able to achieve that without:

- an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) application, like [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/) or [Talend](http://www.talend.com/products/data-integration) or [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aETL_tools).
  That will certainly be like using a hammer to crush an ant though.
- some other external data processing pipeline, in Python or some other programming language.
- VBA (wether through macros or hand coded).
  VBA has been really good at doing that sort of things in Access for literally decades.
  Since you are using Excel and Access, staying within that realm looks like the best solution for solving your issue.
- Just use queries:
  You import the data without transformation to a table whose sole purpose is to accommodate the data from Excel; then you create queries from that raw data to add the missing information and massage the data before appending the result into your final destination table.
  That solution has the advantage of letting you create simple steps in Access that you can easily record using macros.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question some time ago and decided it would be easier to do it in Python. Gord asked me to share, and here it is (sorry about the delay, other projects took priority for a while).

```
"""
Routine to migrate the S7 data from MySQL to the new Access
database.

We're using the pyodbc libraries to connect to Microsoft Access
Note that there are 32- and 64-bit versions of these libraries
available but in order to work the word-length for pyodbc and by
implication Python and all its associated compiled libraries must
match that of MS Access. Which is an arse as I've just had to
delete my 64-bit installation of Python and replace it and all
the libraries with the 32-bit version. 

Tim Greening-Jackson 08 May 2013 (timATgreening-jackson.com)
"""

import pyodbc
import re
import datetime
import tkFileDialog
from Tkinter import *

class S7Incident:
    """
    Class containing the records downloaded from the S7.INCIDENTS table 
    """
    def __init__(self, id_incident, priority, begin, acknowledge,
         diagnose, workaround,fix, handoff, lro, nlro,
         facility, ctas, summary, raised, code):
    self.id_incident=unicode(id_incident)
    self.priority = {u'P1':1, u'P2':2, u'P3':3, u'P4':4, u'P5':5} [unicode(priority.upper())]
    self.begin = begin
    self.acknowledge = acknowledge
    self.diagnose = diagnose
    self.workaround = workaround
    self.fix = fix
    self.handoff = True if handoff else False
    self.lro = True if lro else False
    self.nlro = True if nlro else False
    self.facility = unicode(facility)
    self.ctas = ctas
    self.summary = "** NONE ***" if type(summary) is NoneType else summary.replace("'","")
    self.raised = raised.replace("'","")
    self.code = 0 if code is None else code
    self.production = None
    self.dbid = None

    def __repr__(self):
    return "[{}] ID:{} P{} Prod:{} Begin:{} A:{} D:+{}s W:+{}s F:+{}s\nH/O:{} LRO:{} NLRO:{} Facility={} CTAS={}\nSummary:'{}',Raised:'{}',Code:{}".format(
        self.id_incident,self.dbid, self.priority, self.production, self.begin,
        self.acknowledge, self.diagnose, self.workaround, self.fix,
        self.handoff, self.lro, self.nlro, self.facility, self.ctas,
        self.summary, self.raised, self.code)

    def ProcessIncident(self, cursor, facilities, productions):
    """
    Produces the SQL necessary to insert the incident in to the Access
    database, executes it and then gets the autonumber ID (dbid) of the newly
    created incident (this is used so LRO, NRLO CTAS and AD1 can refer to
    their parent incident.

    If the incident is classed as LRO, NLRO, CTAS then the appropriate
    record is created. Returns the dbid.
    """
    if self.raised.upper() in productions:
        self.production = productions[self.raised.upper()]
    else:
       self.production = 0

    sql="""INSERT INTO INCIDENTS (ID_INCIDENT, PRIORITY, FACILITY, BEGIN,
    ACKNOWLEDGE, DIAGNOSE, WORKAROUND, FIX, HANDOFF, SUMMARY, RAISED, CODE, PRODUCTION)
    VALUES ('{}', {}, {}, #{}#, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, '{}', '{}', {}, {})
    """.format(self.id_incident, self.priority, facilities[self.facility], self.begin,
       self.acknowledge, self.diagnose, self.workaround, self.fix,
       self.handoff, self.summary, self.raised, self.code, self.production)
    cursor.execute(sql)
    cursor.execute("SELECT @@IDENTITY")
    self.dbid = cursor.fetchone()[0]

    if self.lro:
        self.ProcessLRO(cursor, facilities[self.facility])

    if self.nlro:
        self.ProcessNLRO(cursor, facilities[self.facility])

    if self.ctas:
        self.ProcessCTAS(cursor, facilities[self.facility], self.ctas)

    return self.dbid

    def ProcessLRO(self, cursor, facility):
    sql = "INSERT INTO LRO (PID, DURATION, FACILITY) VALUES ({}, {}, {})"\
          .format(self.dbid, self.workaround, facility)
    cursor.execute(sql)

    def ProcessNLRO(self, cursor, facility):
    sql = "INSERT INTO NLRO (PID, DURATION, FACILITY) VALUES ({}, {}, {})"\
          .format(self.dbid, self.workaround, facility)
    cursor.execute(sql)

    def ProcessCTAS(self, cursor, facility, code):
    sql = "INSERT INTO CTAS (PID, DURATION, FACILITY, CODE) VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {})"\
          .format(self.dbid, self.workaround, facility, self.ctas)
    cursor.execute(sql)


class S7AD1:
    """
    S7.AD1 records.
    """
    def __init__(self, id_ad1, date, ref, commentary, adjustment):
    self.id_ad1 = id_ad1
    self.date = date
    self.ref = unicode(ref)
    self.commentary = unicode(commentary)
    self.adjustment = float(adjustment)
    self.pid = 0
    self.production = 0

    def __repr__(self):
    return "[{}] Date:{} Parent:{} PID:{} Amount:{} Commentary: {} "\
           .format(self.id_ad1, self.date.strftime("%d/%m/%y"), self.ref, self.pid, self.adjustment, self.commentary)

    def SetPID(self, pid):
    self.pid = pid

    def SetProduction(self, p):
    self.production = p

    def Process(self, cursor):
    sql = "INSERT INTO AD1 (pid, begin, commentary, production, adjustment) VALUES ({}, #{}#, '{}', {}, {})"\
          .format(self.pid, self.date.strftime("%d/%m/%y"), self.commentary, self.production, self.adjustment)
    cursor.execute(sql)

class S7Financial:
    """
    S7 monthly financial summary of income and penalties from S7.FINANCIALS table.
    These are identical in the new database
    """
    def __init__(self, month, year, gco, cta, support, sc1, sc2, sc3, ad1):
    self.begin = datetime.date(year, month, 1)
    self.gco = float(gco)
    self.cta = float(cta)
    self.support = float(support)
    self.sc1 = float(sc1)
    self.sc2 = float(sc2)
    self.sc3 = float(sc3)
    self.ad1 = float(ad1)

    def __repr__(self):
    return "Period: {} GCO:{:.2f} CTA:{:.2f} SUP:{:.2f} SC1:{:.2f} SC2:{:.2f} SC3:{:.2f} AD1:{:.2f}"\
           .format(self.start.strftime("%m/%y"), self.gco, self.cta, self.support, self.sc1, self.sc2, self.sc3, self.ad1)

    def Process(self, cursor):
    """
    Insert in to FINANCIALS table
    """
    sql = "INSERT INTO FINANCIALS (BEGIN, GCO, CTA, SUPPORT, SC1, SC2, SC3, AD1) VALUES (#{}#, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},{})"\
          .format(self.begin, self.gco, self.cta, self.support, self.sc1, self.sc2, self.sc3, self.ad1)
    cursor.execute(sql)

class S7SC3:
    """
    Miscellaneous S7 SC3 stuff. The new table is identical to the old one. 
    """
    def __init__(self, begin, month, year, p1ot, p2ot, totchg, succchg, chgwithinc, fldchg, egychg):
    self.begin = begin
    self.p1ot = p1ot
    self.p2ot = p2ot
    self.changes = totchg
    self.successful = succchg
    self.incidents = chgwithinc
    self.failed = fldchg
    self.emergency = egychg

    def __repr__(self):
    return "{} P1:{} P2:{} CHG:{} SUC:{} INC:{} FLD:{} EGY:{}"\
           .format(self.period.strftime("%m/%y"), self.p1ot, self.p1ot, self.changes, self.successful, self.incidents, self.failed, self.emergency)


    def Process(self, cursor):
    """
    Inserts a record in to the Access database
    """
    sql = "INSERT INTO SC3 (BEGIN, P1OT, P2OT, CHANGES, SUCCESSFUL, INCIDENTS, FAILED, EMERGENCY) VALUES\
        (#{}#, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {})"\
          .format(self.begin, self.p1ot, self.p2ot, self.changes, self.successful, self.incidents, self.failed, self.emergency)
    cursor.execute(sql)

def ConnectToAccessFile():
    """
    Prompts the user for an Access database file, connects, creates a cursor,
    cleans out the tables which are to be replaced, gets a hash of the facilities
    table keyed on facility name returning facility id
    """
    # Prompts the user to select which Access DB file he wants to use and then attempts to connect
    root = Tk()
    dbname = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, title="Select output database", filetypes=[('Access 2010', '*.accdb')])
    root.destroy()
    # Connect to the Access (new) database and clean its existing incidents etc. tables out as
    # these will be replaced with the new data
    dbcxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+dbname+";")
    dbcursor=dbcxn.cursor()
    print("Connected to {}".format(dbname))
    for table in ["INCIDENTS", "AD1", "LRO", "NLRO", "CTAS", "SC3", "PRODUCTIONS", "FINANCIALS"]:
    print("Clearing table {}...".format(table))
    dbcursor.execute("DELETE * FROM {}".format(table))
    # Get the list of facilities from the Access database...
    dbcursor.execute("SELECT id, facility FROM facilities")
    rows = dbcursor.fetchall()
    dbfacilities = {unicode(row[1]):row[0] for row in rows}
    return dbcxn, dbcursor, dbfacilities

# Entry point

incre = re.compile("INC\d{12}[A-Z]?") # Regex that matches incident references

try:
    dbcxn, dbcursor, dbfacilities = ConnectToAccessFile()
    # Connect to the MySQL S7 (old) database and read the incidents and ad1 tables
    s7cxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=s7; UID=root; PASSWORD=********; OPTION=3")
    print("Connected to MySQL S7 database")
    s7cursor = s7cxn.cursor()
    s7cursor.execute("""
    SELECT id_incident, priority, begin, acknowledge,
    diagnose, workaround, fix, handoff, lro, nlro,
    facility, ctas, summary, raised, code FROM INCIDENTS""")
    rows = s7cursor.fetchall()
    # Discard any incidents which don't have a reference of the form INC... as they are ancient
    print("Fetching incidents")
    s7incidents = {unicode(row[0]):S7Incident(*row) for row in rows if incre.match(row[0])}

    # Get the list of productions from the S7 database to replace the one we've just deleted ...

    print("Fetching productions")    
    s7cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT RAISED FROM INCIDENTS")
    rows = s7cursor.fetchall()
    s7productions = [r[0] for r in rows]

    # ... now get the AD1s ...

    print("Fetching AD1s")    
    s7cursor.execute("SELECT id_ad1, date, ref, commentary, adjustment from AD1")
    rows = s7cursor.fetchall()
    s7ad1s = [S7AD1(*row) for row in rows]

    # ... and the financial records ...

    print("Fetching Financials")    
    s7cursor.execute("SELECT month, year, gco, cta, support, sc1, sc2, sc3, ad1 FROM Financials")
    rows = s7cursor.fetchall()
    s7financials = [S7Financial(*row) for row in rows]
    print("Writing financials ({})".format(len(s7financials)))
    [p.Process(dbcursor) for p in s7financials]

    # ... and the SC3s.

    print("Fetching SC3s")    
    s7cursor.execute("SELECT begin, month, year, p1ot, p2ot, totchg, succhg, chgwithinc, fldchg, egcychg from SC3")
    rows = s7cursor.fetchall()
    s7sc3s = [S7SC3(*row) for row in rows]
    print("Writing SC3s ({})".format(len(s7sc3s)))
    [p.Process(dbcursor) for p in s7sc3s]

    # Re-create the productions table in the new database. Note we refer to production
    # by number in the incidents table so need to do the SELECT @@IDENTITY to give us the
    # autonumber index. To make sure everything is case-insensitive convert the
    # hash keys to UPPERCASE.

    dbproductions = {}
    print("Writing productions ({})".format(len(s7productions)))
    for p in sorted(s7productions):
    dbcursor.execute("INSERT INTO PRODUCTIONS (PRODUCTION) VALUES ('{}')".format(p))
    dbcursor.execute("SELECT @@IDENTITY")
    dbproductions[p.upper()] = dbcursor.fetchone()[0]


    # Now process the incidents etc. that we have retrieved from the S7 database

    print("Writing incidents ({})".format(len(s7incidents)))
    [s7incidents[k].ProcessIncident(dbcursor, dbfacilities, dbproductions) for k in sorted(s7incidents)]

    # Match the new parent incident IDs in the AD1s and then write to the new table. Some
    # really old AD1s don't have the parent incident reference in the REF field, it is just
    # mentioned SOMEWHERE in the commentary. So if the REF field doesn't match then do a
    # re.search (not re.match!) for it. It isn't essential to match these older AD1s with
    # their parent incident, but it is quite useful (and tidy).

    print("Matching and writing AD1s".format(len(s7ad1s)))
    for a in s7ad1s:
    if a.ref in s7incidents:
        a.SetPID(s7incidents[a.ref].dbid)
        a.SetProduction(s7incidents[a.ref].production)
    else:
        z=incre.search(a.commentary)
        if z and z.group() in s7incidents:
        a.SetPID(s7incidents[z.group()].dbid)
        a.SetProduction(s7incidents[z.group()].production)

    a.Process(dbcursor)

    print("Comitting changes")
    dbcursor.commit()
finally:
    print("Closing databases")
    dbcxn.close()
    s7cxn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the file has additional complications in terms of mangled data which will require a degree of processing which is a pain to do in Excel but trivially simple in Python. So I will re-use some Python 2.x scripts which use the XLWT/XLRD libraries to munge the spreadsheet.

Comment: I consider myself quite conversant in VBA and I'm working hard on improving my Python skills. It would be a great addition to Stack Overflow (and I'd be most grateful) if you would edit your answer with an example (or two) of the type of transformations you need to do that would be "trivially simple" in Python but would be "a pain to do in Excel". Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure given the appropriate knowledge of VBA it would be simple. But as I mentioned I just don't have the time (or inclination) to get up that particular learning curve. I'll post the code once it's done hopefully later today UK time.